# How persistent are "continue this discussion in chat" rooms?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Occasionally a colloquy on a post will prompt a commenter to move the discussion to chat, as [recently happened to me](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72611/23970). The chat room thereby created: is it persistent, or does it expire after some time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rooms with any sort of meaningful content exist forever.

As outlined [in the chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention), "A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users." Any such room is available for everyone (including non site members) to find [on this list of RPG.SE chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com), for as long as the Stack exists. Also they're seeded to Google.

The original Question/Answer page doesn't automatically get a link to that chat room, because anything productive to improving the main site content should be applied via edits to the questions and answers. The chat is there to *reduce* the clutter so questions and answers are easily found, not to add to the reading someone needs to do to get a good answer.

Comment: ahh... thanks. I'd been poking around in the comments portion of the site's FAQ, not the chat FAQ.

Comment: As an aside, is the *discussion moved to chat* link in the comment the sole indicator that a chat exists about a question or answer?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Added a line about how they can be found and why they aren't automagically linked on the main site.